# How to sample from unknown distribution

Tags: probability-distributions

[image]

Let's just assume on the picture we have a prob. distribution of aliens height on a Mars. We know for sure, the area below the curve is 1.

But I have a different question. How do we approach sampling from unique distributions as this is? Taking mean, variance, standard deviation out of it, etc, would not be really helpful, I guess, or it would be? Basically, I am just interested in how to sample from distributions, which are not well defined such as normal distribution etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You apply the mathematical inverse of the *cumulative distribution function* to numbers randomly sampled from a uniform distribution on the interval $[0,1]$.

---

Suppose for example you want to sample numbers from the exponential distribution which has a probability density function,

$$ f_X(x) = \frac{1}{\tau} e^{-x/\tau}\qquad (0\leq x ),$$

the cumulative distribution function is defined as,

$$ F(z) = P( X < x)$$ 
$$= \int_0^z f_X(x) dx $$
$$= \frac{1}{\tau} \int_0^z e^{-x/\tau} dx $$
$$= e^{-z/\tau} - 1 $$

Now we have that,

$$F(z) = 1 - e^{-z/\tau},$$

the mathematical inverse of this function is,

$$F^{-1}(z) =-\tau \log(1-z).$$

======

Now we will apply the method I described at the beginning of this answer to get numbers sampled from the exponential distribution.

First I need a source of uniformly random numbers on the interval from $[0,1]$. I will use random.org to generate these numbers.

https://www.random.org/decimal-fractions/

======

I generated 100 random number sampled from the uniform distribution on $[0,1]$ using the random.org link above. The histrogram from these numbers follows.

[image]

Then I applied $F^{-1}(z)$ to each of these numbers (I chose $\tau=1$). The resulting list of numbers obtained from this process obeys an exponential distribution. Their histogram is shown below.

[image]

You can see that the histogram has changed to have a shape consistent with an exponential distribution.

Comment: Spencer, could you please give me more details, perhaps a simple example. I have an intuition about it, but I am not really sure. Or perhaps guide me with technique, method I can google it. Thanks.

Comment: Sure I will try to flesh out the answer a bit.

Comment: You may also find a previous answer I provided here helpful. 

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2613604/calculate-a-gaussian-distribution-with-zero-mean-and-standard-deviation/2614139#2614139

Comment: Does this sufficiently answer your question?

Comment: Yes, this is very helpful. I appreciate it a lot.